# How to restore Azure Sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure

i'm working on Azure and while deploying my terraform release somehow i made a mistake which deleted my ressources, i managed to restore my web app but failed to restore my Sql servers that contains my Databases. does anyone knows how to restore sql sevrer on azure ? if its possible of course.
All what i can found on internet is how to restore Sql DataBase but not the sql server as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups)

Comment: [Recover an Azure SQL database by using automated database backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups)?

Comment: Please call the Azure Support to help you restore the Azure SQL Server, you can follow the steps in my answer(updated).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes i'll call support help idont have another choice at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you deleted the Azure SQL server, all the resources, include databases and backup will be deleted. You can not restore the it by yourself.

Reference [Deleted database restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups#deleted-database-restore):
[image]

In this case, you should call Azure Support in 7 days, they can help you restore the Azure SQL server and the databases.

Create the support on Portal, you could follow these steps:
Step1:
[image]

Step2
[image]

Step3
[image]

Hope this helps.